# My updated Azure App Services web app is not served after a successful deploy. How do I fix that?

Tags: express, azure-web-app-service

I built a working node.js Express app using the tutorial "Deploy Express.js to Azure App Service using Visual Studio Code", see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/deploy-nodejs-azure-app-service-with-visual-studio-code?tabs=bash.

This first version was deployed and worked successfully using only Get requests.

I made some minor changes to include Post requests and deployed that update. This takes 18 minutes to deploy, but the new version is not served to my browser, just the old version. Going to my Azure dashboard and clicking my app service and selecting Browse there, it still shows the old version 2 days after the successful update deploy.

Another problem is that after a long time, say overnight, a request to the app's api does not get answered. My Safari browser says the server stopped responding. But a second request immediately after does get a response, but still with the same old version.

This JSON file may be useful.

```
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/3603adff-9823-408c-980c-ea71f06376ce/resourceGroups/AcesTraderExpress-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/AcesTraderExpress",
    "name": "AcesTraderExpress",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "kind": "app,linux",
    "location": "East US",
    "properties": {
        "name": "AcesTraderExpress",
        "state": "Running",
        "hostNames": [
            "acestraderexpress.azurewebsites.net"
        ],
        "webSpace": "AcesTraderExpress-rg-EastUSwebspace-Linux",
        "selfLink": "https://waws-prod-blu-217.api.azurewebsites.windows.net:454/subscriptions/3603adff-9823-408c-980c-ea71f06376ce/webspaces/AcesTraderExpress-rg-EastUSwebspace-Linux/sites/AcesTraderExpress",
        "repositorySiteName": "AcesTraderExpress",
        "owner": null,
        "usageState": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "adminEnabled": true,
        "enabledHostNames": [
            "acestraderexpress.azurewebsites.net",
            "acestraderexpress.scm.azurewebsites.net"
        ],
        "siteProperties": {
            "metadata": null,
            "properties": [
                {
                    "name": "LinuxFxVersion",
                    "value": "NODE|14-lts"
                },
                {
                    "name": "WindowsFxVersion",
                    "value": null
                }
            ],
            "appSettings": null
        },
        "availabilityState": 0,
        "sslCertificates": null,
        "csrs": [],
        "cers": null,
        "siteMode": null,
        "hostNameSslStates": [
            {
                "name": "acestraderexpress.azurewebsites.net",
                "sslState": 0,
                "ipBasedSslResult": null,
                "virtualIP": null,
                "thumbprint": null,
                "toUpdate": null,
                "toUpdateIpBasedSsl": null,
                "ipBasedSslState": 0,
                "hostType": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "acestraderexpress.scm.azurewebsites.net",
                "sslState": 0,
                "ipBasedSslResult": null,
                "virtualIP": null,
                "thumbprint": null,
                "toUpdate": null,
                "toUpdateIpBasedSsl": null,
                "ipBasedSslState": 0,
                "hostType": 1
            }
        ],
        "computeMode": null,
        "serverFarm": null,
        "serverFarmId": "/subscriptions/3603adff-9823-408c-980c-ea71f06376ce/resourceGroups/AcesTraderExpress-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/AcesTraderExpress-plan",
        "reserved": true,
        "isXenon": false,
        "hyperV": false,
        "lastModifiedTimeUtc": "2021-11-24T21:28:18.1666667",
        "storageRecoveryDefaultState": "Running",
        "contentAvailabilityState": 0,
        "runtimeAvailabilityState": 0,
        "siteConfig": {
            "numberOfWorkers": 1,
            "defaultDocuments": null,
            "netFrameworkVersion": null,
            "phpVersion": null,
            "pythonVersion": null,
            "nodeVersion": null,
            "powerShellVersion": null,
            "linuxFxVersion": "NODE|14-lts",
            "windowsFxVersion": null,
            "requestTracingEnabled": null,
            "remoteDebuggingEnabled": null,
            "remoteDebuggingVersion": null,
            "httpLoggingEnabled": null,
            "azureMonitorLogCategories": null,
            "acrUseManagedIdentityCreds": false,
            "acrUserManagedIdentityID": null,
            "logsDirectorySizeLimit": null,
            "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": null,
            "publishingUsername": null,
            "publishingPassword": null,
            "appSettings": null,
            "metadata": null,
            "connectionStrings": null,
            "machineKey": null,
            "handlerMappings": null,
            "documentRoot": null,
            "scmType": null,
            "use32BitWorkerProcess": null,
            "webSocketsEnabled": null,
            "alwaysOn": false,
            "javaVersion": null,
            "javaContainer": null,
            "javaContainerVersion": null,
            "appCommandLine": null,
            "managedPipelineMode": null,
            "virtualApplications": null,
            "winAuthAdminState": null,
            "winAuthTenantState": null,
            "customAppPoolIdentityAdminState": null,
            "customAppPoolIdentityTenantState": null,
            "runtimeADUser": null,
            "runtimeADUserPassword": null,
            "loadBalancing": null,
            "routingRules": null,
            "experiments": null,
            "limits": null,
            "autoHealEnabled": null,
            "autoHealRules": null,
            "tracingOptions": null,
            "vnetName": null,
            "vnetRouteAllEnabled": null,
            "vnetPrivatePortsCount": null,
            "publicNetworkAccess": null,
            "cors": null,
            "push": null,
            "apiDefinition": null,
            "apiManagementConfig": null,
            "autoSwapSlotName": null,
            "localMySqlEnabled": null,
            "managedServiceIdentityId": null,
            "xManagedServiceIdentityId": null,
            "keyVaultReferenceIdentity": null,
            "ipSecurityRestrictions": null,
            "scmIpSecurityRestrictions": null,
            "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain": null,
            "http20Enabled": false,
            "minTlsVersion": null,
            "scmMinTlsVersion": null,
            "ftpsState": null,
            "preWarmedInstanceCount": null,
            "functionAppScaleLimit": 0,
            "healthCheckPath": null,
            "fileChangeAuditEnabled": null,
            "functionsRuntimeScaleMonitoringEnabled": null,
            "websiteTimeZone": null,
            "minimumElasticInstanceCount": 0,
            "azureStorageAccounts": null,
            "sitePort": null
        },
        "deploymentId": "AcesTraderExpress",
        "slotName": null,
        "trafficManagerHostNames": null,
        "sku": "Free",
        "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
        "targetSwapSlot": null,
        "hostingEnvironment": null,
        "hostingEnvironmentProfile": null,
        "clientAffinityEnabled": true,
        "clientCertEnabled": false,
        "clientCertMode": 0,
        "clientCertExclusionPaths": null,
        "hostNamesDisabled": false,
        "domainVerificationIdentifiers": null,
        "customDomainVerificationId": "32CA73F9034F12CA2A538C5F30E96A3BDF81DFD04981F8BFE65F69C4E24A69E6",
        "kind": "app,linux",
        "inboundIpAddress": "20.49.104.15",
        "possibleInboundIpAddresses": "20.49.104.15",
        "ftpUsername": "AcesTraderExpress\\$AcesTraderExpress",
        "ftpsHostName": "ftps://waws-prod-blu-217.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot",
        "outboundIpAddresses": "40.76.167.202,52.146.70.44,52.146.70.103,52.146.68.209,52.146.68.246,52.146.69.57,20.49.104.15",
        "possibleOutboundIpAddresses": "40.76.167.202,52.146.70.44,52.146.70.103,52.146.68.209,52.146.68.246,52.146.69.57,52.146.70.115,52.146.70.118,52.146.70.158,52.146.66.148,52.146.71.5,40.76.165.150,40.76.167.156,40.76.167.157,52.146.68.142,52.146.64.68,52.146.65.22,52.146.65.23,52.191.239.27,52.191.239.78,52.191.239.120,52.224.200.31,52.224.201.90,52.224.202.78,20.49.104.15",
        "containerSize": 0,
        "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
        "suspendedTill": null,
        "siteDisabledReason": 0,
        "functionExecutionUnitsCache": null,
        "maxNumberOfWorkers": null,
        "homeStamp": "waws-prod-blu-217",
        "cloningInfo": null,
        "hostingEnvironmentId": null,
        "tags": null,
        "resourceGroup": "AcesTraderExpress-rg",
        "defaultHostName": "acestraderexpress.azurewebsites.net",
        "slotSwapStatus": null,
        "httpsOnly": false,
        "redundancyMode": 0,
        "inProgressOperationId": null,
        "geoDistributions": null,
        "privateEndpointConnections": [],
        "buildVersion": null,
        "targetBuildVersion": null,
        "migrationState": null,
        "eligibleLogCategories": "AppServiceAppLogs,AppServiceAuditLogs,AppServiceConsoleLogs,AppServiceHTTPLogs,AppServiceIPSecAuditLogs,AppServicePlatformLogs,ScanLogs",
        "storageAccountRequired": false,
        "virtualNetworkSubnetId": null,
        "keyVaultReferenceIdentity": "SystemAssigned"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that my problem was that the deploy operation failed. But I missed the notification at the end, so assumed success. Later tries showed the deploy as failing. But with deploys taking 8-10 minutes, it's easy to get up and walk away.

Answer (score 0):

I am following [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-http-post-request-work-in-node-js/) website. Initially I am added only Get request and deployed to azure portal using this doc [Deploy Node.js Express.js to App Service from Visual Studio Code - Azure | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/deploy-nodejs-azure-app-service-with-visual-studio-code?tabs=bash).
(**Note:** Skipped the Local git deployment process).

Directly deployed using Deploy to Web app in `Visual Studio Code`

[image]

Then, I am adding the below code in visual studio with `Post` Request

Add below code in `app.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

// App using express node module

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));

// Get request

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

// Post Request

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    var num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
    var num2 = Number(req.body.num2);
    var result = num1 + num2 ;
    res.send("Addition - " + result);
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('server is running on port 3000');
})
```

Added the below code in `index.html`

```
< !DOCTYPE html>
< html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    < head>
        < meta charset="utf-8">
        < title>Calculator</title>
    < /head>
    < body>
        < h1>Simple Calculator.< /h1>
        < form action="/" method="post">
            < input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="First Number">
            < input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Second Number">
            < button type="submit" name="submit">
                calculator
            < /button>
        < /form>
    < /body>
< /html>
```

After added **Post** Method request, I was deployed again in a Azure Web App. (By Default it was deployed in Linux app service).

I can view the results in Browser

[image]